# center div of arbitrary width inside another div

Tags: html, css

Please help me center a div that does not have a predefined width, inside another div. Please see the code below (or on jsbin at http://jsbin.com/ufivif). Thanks.

EDIT: the problem is that I need the caption below the image to be aligned to the left edge of the image. So `text-align: center` on the container does not work for me.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<style>
  .container
  {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5em;
    position: relative;
  }
  .container img
  {
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  .container .image
  {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Telefunken_FuBK_test_pattern.svg/500px-Telefunken_FuBK_test_pattern.svg.png"/>
      <div class="caption">test image</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: If you don't know the width of the <div>, you'll have to use JavaScript. If you had a set width, then you could use margin-left: -'half of the length'px; or margin: 0 auto;.

Comment: @akonsu If you are tring to center image class, try to set right,left align to auto like this: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `display: inline-block;` and `text-align:center`

http://jsbin.com/ufivif/5

```
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .container
  {
    border: 1px solid gold;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .container .image
  {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .container .image img
  {
      border: 1px solid #9C6963 ;
      padding: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: this won't work in <IE8 though, the text-align:center solutions are safer i think...

Comment: @ptriek It will, if you'd give a display:inline to any IE<8 browser afterwards. Either via CSS hack or via Conditional Comment http://jsbin.com/ufivif/9 as an example

Answer (score 1):

So you need the image centered and not the text here's a way to fix it.

```
<style>
  .container 
  {
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 5em;
   text-align: center;
  }

  .imageWrapper 
  {
   display: inline;
  }

  .container .image
  {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
  }

 .caption
 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 1em;
 }
</style>

<div class="container">
 <div class='imageWrapper'>
  <div class="image">
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Telefunken_FuBK_test_pattern.svg/500px-Telefunken_FuBK_test_pattern.svg.png">
   <div class="caption">Image Text</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

While this doesn't get the borders to line up properly this does get the image centered and the text to the left of the image.

Comment: thanks. I omitted an important part, I need to have a left aligned caption. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.image { margin: auto }
```

Comment: can't margin: auto a div without a width because the default width of the div is 100% of the parent and margin auto just makes sure the margin on left and right if there is any is equal.  Since the width is 100% there are no margins

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in centering on this one div, you can use the text-align: center in the parent:

```
#arbitrary
{
    width: 750px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

<div id="arbitrary">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Telefunken_FuBK_test_pattern.svg/500px-Telefunken_FuBK_test_pattern.svg.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center .image div the Try using this CSS:

```
.container 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.container .image
{
    margin: 0 auto
}
```